# Yii2 need data in a object format

Tags: php, yii2

following code gives result in an array format. I need it in object format.
Below is the piece of code,

```
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();

$command = $connection->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `tbl_ironing_items_price` iip ".
"LEFT JOIN `tbl_ironing_items` ii ON iip.service_id = ii.id WHERE iip.customer_id =  ".$pid);

$result = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: you mean you need  a models  collection? and of which  model?

Comment: yes, need models collection

Comment: of which  model ?

Comment: This is exactly what gii is supposed to make painless - suggest you read the yii2 guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html esp. section 6, Working with Databases

Answer (score 4):

you can set fetch mode to queryAll arguments

```
$result = $command->queryAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

Comment: @maheshkalantre : Kindly Accept answer if it is working :) This is good habbit and inspires others to solve more questions for others unconditionally. God Bless.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code with more Yii2 way.

```
TblIroningItemsPrice::find()
->select('tbl_ironing_items_price.*')
->leftJoin('tbl_ironing_items', '`tbl_ironing_items_price`.`service_id` = `tbl_ironing_items`.`id`')
->where(['tbl_ironing_items_price.customer_id' => $pid])
->with('tbl_ironing_items')
->all();
```